# Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. (Angular 12)

Tags: angular, forms

My Error in Console:

```
Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

       Example:

       
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });
    at Function.missingFormException (forms.js:1432)
    at FormGroupDirective._checkFormPresent (forms.js:5371)
    at FormGroupDirective.ngOnChanges (forms.js:5144)
    at FormGroupDirective.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.js:1498)
    at callHook (core.js:2536)
    at callHooks (core.js:2495)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2446)
    at selectIndexInternal (core.js:8428)
    at ɵɵadvance (core.js:8411)
    at PriceCategoryManagementComponent_ng_container_7_Template (template.html:25)
```

A simplified version of my Code:

*price-category-management.component.ts*

```
// happens on click
openEditor(id: number): void {
  this.current = this.list.find((category) => category.id === id);
  this.priceService.getPrices().subscribe((data) => {
    this.prices = data.filter((price) => price.priceCategory.id === id);
    if (this.prices) {
      this.createForm();
      this.priceForm = this.createPriceForm();
    }
  });
}

createPriceForm(): FormGroup {
  if (this.prices) {
    const group: any = {};

    this.prices.forEach((price) => {
      group[price.product?.id || 'price' + price.id] = new FormControl(
        price.price
      );
    });
    return new FormGroup(group);
  }
  return null;
}
```

*price-category-management.component.html*

```
<form *ngIf="priceForm" [formGroup]="priceForm">
  <div *ngFor="let price of prices" class="price-container">
    {{ price.product.id }} - {{ price.product?.name }}
    <mat-form-field class="price">
      <mat-label>Price</mat-label>
      <input matInput [formControlName]="price.product.id" />
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</form>
```

The values are shown correctly in the input fields, everything is alright except this error occurs in the console.

I have secured the view by using `*ngIf`, I create the form after getting the needed data from http request, also creating form if the data exists only.

The form is created after clicking on a button, so there is no connection to the `constructor` or `ngOnInit`.

Any leads?

---

### I tried

```
priceForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
```

and using FormBuilder:

```
createPriceForm(): FormGroup {
  if (this.prices) {
    const group = this.fb.group({});

    this.prices.forEach((price) => {
      group.addControl('' + price.product?.id, new FormControl(price.price));
    });
    console.log(this.prices, group);
    return group;
  }
  return this.fb.group({});
}
```

Comment: Of course you imported `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` into the current module, right ?

Comment: @Emilien Yes I did. Or else the form wouldnt work at all

Comment: Is this error happening when the component is created or when you click the button?

Comment: @ding on clicking a button.

Comment: Try initializing the `priceForm` property on declaration as an empty `FormGroup` object and then add each control when you receive the data. You'll have to set a boolean flag for your *ngIf condition. I would look into using `Form Builder` for this: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder

Comment: @ding I did, I updated the question. Sadly the error still shows up.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `return null;` in your `createPriceForm` function, because at first, the `priceForm` is null (causing the error in the console), and then gets assigned (making it work).

I would assume that the data you're getting in the `openEditor()` function doesn't contain the prices when it's first getting invoked, thus causing the `createPriceForm()` to return `null` until you actually get the prices.

A simple check of the `this.prices` before you invoke `createPriceForm()` should do the trick.

```
// Inside openEditor function
if(this.prices) {
    this.priceForm = this.createPriceForm();
}
```

Comment: Good point at checking prices there, but the error still exists.

Comment: Irrelevant point: But if this.prices is an array, update the if statement like this `if(this.prices?.length)`